# Saving data from views.py in django DB

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

in my Django App, I have created a model under my models.py. I am wondering if I can save data directly from my views.py. This is what I have tried:

```
userinfo.info = UserInfo.objects.create(info=response.text)
userinfo.save()
```

where UserInfo is my model name, and info is the field name. Thanks

Comment: What is the variable userinfo? `userinfo = UserInfo.objects.create(info=response.text)` should be enough.

Comment: Hi, it was an instance of the model. I tried using UserInfo.objects.create(info=response.text) but had no luck. Can you suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What do you want to do? change the `info` field of the instance? `userinfo.info = response.text` and `userinfo.save()`?

Comment: I just want to save response.text in the database.

Comment: Does `userinfo.info = response.text` and then `userinfo.save()` as in my comment above not do what you want?

Comment: Thanks, it was my bad I was overlooking the DB and not viewing the records. my initial code worked fine. Thanks for the discussion